# GWT 'String' toLowerCase and toUpperCase emulation

Tags: gwt

Why is the emulation for toLowerCase and toUpperCase methods on a string different in GWT ?

`public String toLowerCase() {
    return asNativeString().toLowerCase();
  }`

`public String toUpperCase() {
    return asNativeString().toLocaleUpperCase();
}`

The uppercase method is doing Locale specific conversion, which is causing problems for us with Turkish users. Is there a good workaround to make toUpperCase to work similar to toLowerCase

**Code :**
https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/a90832fec9a56f4cb83ed009c7048e0a8d196fe8/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/String.java#L708

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, and a regression in 2.8.0. In any case, you should not rely on `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` output, as they are by definition locale-dependent (though that's not supposed to be the case in GWT, for backwards compatibility, as noted in the comments in the linked file); you should pass an explicit locale, most likely `Locale.ROOT`.